# Is there a way to create operator/function overload for container type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have some class like:

```cpp
class A {
A& operator=(const A& a);
A& operator=(const int a);
A& operator=(const std::string& a);
};
```

I made type trait for iterable `is_iterable`;
How to implement overload for `operator=` for iterable types?

My approach:

```cpp
template<typename TContainer, std::enable_if_t<is_iterable<TContainer>::value>>
A& operator=(const TContainer& val) {
// do stuff
}
```

but it doesn't work causing `no viable overload` error when i try to feed `std::list` or `std::vector`.

So, how to fix it and is it possible to use that kind of overload?

Comment: How about posting a [mcve] so others might copy-paste and reproduce your error?

Comment: You need to make the second template-argument defaulted. Or better yet, use SFINAE on the return-type instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `is_iterable<TContainer>::value` is true, `std::enable_if_t<is_iterable<TContainer>::value>` is `void`, which is not a valid non-type template parameter. Define your container overload as

```
template<typename TContainer,
         std::enable_if_t<is_iterable<TContainer>{}, int*> = nullptr>
A& operator=(const TContainer&)
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18dcbbea9089e71a)

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<condition>* = 0` would be simpler. Anyway, I would on principle use SFINAE in the return-type instead, to ensure it isn't part of the signature and thus not part of the mangled name.

Comment: Nice, your case worked. Sadly other template incompatible with mine.

Comment: @Deduplicator `void*` is also not a valid non-type argument, although compilers accept it. The return type thing is arguable, I find it harder to read. And the return type is part of the signature for function templates.

Comment: @Sugar I don't understand, what other template is incompatible?

Comment: Hm. Where does it forbid a `void*`? And the return-type may be part of the functions signature, but how exactly it is determined is only relevant for SFINAE. Naturally, if we had concepts already, that would be far better.

Comment: I prefer `,bool> = true` because it looks like a boolean comparison.  ;)

Comment: @Deduplicator You might be right, the wording for that has changed. [temp.param/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4) previously disallowed `void*` but the [latest draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#4) states it differently by referring to `operator<=>`. I *think* `void*` satisfies that, and your version would be better.

Comment: @Praetorian don't worry about it. it's some of legacy code that interfere in my code base.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for but I believe:

```
template<typename TContainer>
A& operator=(const TContainer& container) {
    for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
        // do stuff
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The template will be called only if other overloads does not match to type fed. If the type is not iterable, and error will occur on call to `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: Why use specialization though? Overloading should be fine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You are absolutely right, I will edit my answer.